# How to merge two rows and sum the columns

Tags: sql

| product | quantity | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| milk | 3 | 10 |
| bread | 7 | 3 |
| bread | 5 | 2 |

And my output table should be

| product | total_price |
| --- | --- |
| milk | 30 |
| bread | 31 |

I can't seem to get my code to work. Here is my code

```
SELECT product, (SELECT (quantity*unit_price)
FROM shopping_history AS sh  ) AS total_price
FROM shopping_history
GROUP BY product
```

Comment: Please tag a *single* RDBMS...

Comment: @DaleK That could be an answer.

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags and added a generic SQL tag. Please add back the RDBMS tag you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the aggregate function [`SUM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (which doesn't require a sub-query) e.g.

```
SELECT product, SUM(quantity*unit_price) AS Total_Price
FROM shopping_history
GROUP BY product
```